# Move Background image randomly

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I want to apply animation to the imageview in linear layout. I want to move image randomly in background.

My code is

```
    ImageView image1;
private Animation animation,animation1,animation2,animation3,animation4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.categories);

     image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

     Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomin);
     image1.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
```

I got this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hunt.gilpix.wallpaper/hunt.gilpix.wallpaper.Categories}: java.lang.ClassCastException: hunt.gilpix.wallpaper.Categories cannot be cast to android.view.animation.Animation$AnimationListener
```

Answer (score 0):

Well! Insufficient info to answer!! 
Tell was what exactly u want to do! 
Anyways u can try this: determine how many images u wanna show! Put it in drawable folder. In ur java file pull all that in a int array!
And using thread u can it can randomly change!! (Think of a random num generating idea) ..

Comment: not that, I want to use single image in background and zoom tha and after zoom move that right,left,down or up.